# How to find my Airbrake project ID and project key?

Tags: airbrake

I'm trying to follow the steps described on https://airbrake.io/docs/installing-airbrake/installing-airbrake-in-a-python-app/#configuration to configure Airbrake for a Django project. In particular,

> To configure pybrake you will need your Airbrake project’s `id` and `api_key`, these are available from your project’s settings page.

I'm browsing around on the project's page on airbrake.io, but for the life of me, I can't find any "settings page". How do I find these keys?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to Airbrake's tech support, the "Settings" tab is not visible to non-admin users. However, the project ID is simply the number in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

If someone uses it.
On your project's dashboard look for the top tab called Settings and then top to the right you'll see the info